# Competencies and technologies knowledge for a automated tester

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework

For someone starting to specialize in automated testing, what are the technologies worth to learn? What are the current trends?

Also, any good pointers where to start a professional career in automated testing?

There is Cucumber, Fitness, Quick Test professional, etc..., what do you think is worth to learn? I.e, what are the current industry demands?

Thanks very much, 
Joao

Comment: Selenium is popular, too. But the only responses you are likely to get here are personal opinions.

Comment: As @JoeStrazzere says, as this question stands you're mostly going to get people's opinions. As you've seen there are many tools available and everyone has their favorites.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you work.  Different market segments use different tools and technologies.  I know a little about the server market.  Someone else will need to answer regarding mobile testing.

You will need to learn at least one programming language.  Microsoft-centric shops will probably use C#.  Outside of the Microsoft world, they will probably use Linux with Java, Ruby, Python, or C++.

You probably want to learn SQL.  It doesn't especially matter which RDBMS you use, e.g. Oracle, SQLServer, or Postgresql.

If you are testing web applications, you will probably be asked some UI automation.  There are commercial tools like Quick Test Pro, and there are open-source tools like Watir and Selenium.  You will also want to know some JavaScript.

You need to learn a version control system.  There are lots of options.  I recommend learning Git.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we use Testcomplete to automate the UI tests, you can download the trial and try it out, you'll need knowledge in JScript, run away from record & playback. It has the advantage of working with a lot of technologies (WPF/Silverlight/Java/Flex/JQuery plugins, etc...) but the disadvantage of the license price, as does Telerik Test Studio and QTP.

Most of the job offers I see in QA engineer/test development require either C# or Java.

If you have time take a look at selenium and watir/watij/watin, they are good tools to automate web browsers from what I've read and with a good community.

There are a couple of sites/blogs out there that you should read:

allthingsquality(dot)com

blog(dot)codeship(dot)io/category/testing-tuesday

www(dot)softwaretestingclub(dot)com/